How to modify FLS (Read) on all Fields on all Objects in your Org with Apex
There was no easy article on this topic, and it took me some days to figure this out, and it works! So thought I'd share it here for max searchability. Thanks to sfdcfox and anthony for your support on this.
For each FLS on a particular Permission Set, there's a FieldPermissions record in the background. This script went through over 500 objects in my org, setting every settable field to Read. Combined with System Settings: View All Data and API access, and this Permission Set I created for him, my User can pull all needed data into an external data lake.
It easily could be modified for a number of use cases related to FLS as it relates to one or many Permission Sets.

public with sharing class PermissionSetUpdateBatch implements Database.Stateful, Database.Batchable<String> {
  private String INTEGRATION_BOT_PERMSET_ID = [SELECT Id 
                                             FROM PermissionSet 
                                             WHERE Label = 'Integration Bot View All Records'
                                             LIMIT 1].Id;
  private Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> globalDescribe = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
  private List<FieldPermissions> fieldPermissionsList = [SELECT Id, Field 
                                                       FROM FieldPermissions 
                                                       WHERE ParentID =: INTEGRATION_BOT_PERMSET_ID 
                                                       AND PermissionsRead = true];
private Set<String> fieldsWithPermReadTrue = new Set<String>();

public Iterable<String> start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    System.debug('>>> INTEGRATION_BOT_PERMSET_ID: ' + INTEGRATION_BOT_PERMSET_ID);
    System.debug('>>> fieldPermissionsList: ' + fieldPermissionsList);
    
    for (FieldPermissions fp : fieldPermissionsList) {
        fieldsWithPermReadTrue.add(fp.Field);
    }
    System.debug('>>> fieldsWithPermReadTrue: ' + fieldsWithPermReadTrue);

    List<String> objApiNames;
    System.debug('>>> objApiNames: ' + objApiNames);
    if(Test.isRunningTest()){
        objApiNames = new List<String>();
        objApiNames.add('order');
    } else {
        objApiNames = new List<String>(globalDescribe.keySet());
    }
    return objApiNames;
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<String> objectApiNames){
    List<FieldPermissions> fieldPermissionsForInsert = new List<FieldPermissions>();
    
    for (String objectApiName : objectApiNames) { // loop all SObject
        //EntityDefinition ed = (EntityDefinition)record;
        System.debug('------- objectApiName: ' + objectApiName);

        // get the describe for each individual object
        Schema.SObjectType sobjectType = globalDescribe.get(objectApiName);
        System.debug('------- sobjectType: ' + sobjectType);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objectDescribe = sobjectType.getDescribe();
        
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = objectDescribe.fields.getMap();

        for (String fieldApiName : objectFields.keySet()) { // loop all fields per object
            System.debug('>>>> fieldApiName: ' + fieldApiName);
            Schema.SObjectField sobjectField = objectFields.get(fieldApiName);
            String objectDotField = objectApiName + '.' + fieldApiName;
            
            if (!fieldsWithPermReadTrue.contains(objectDotField)) {
                 FieldPermissions newFP = new FieldPermissions();
                 newFP.ParentId = INTEGRATION_BOT_PERMSET_ID;
                 newFP.SObjectType = objectApiName;
                 newFP.Field = objectDotField;
                 newFP.PermissionsRead = true;
                 fieldPermissionsForInsert.add(newFP);
            }
        }
    }
    Database.insert(fieldPermissionsForInsert, false);    
}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    // execute any post-processing operations
}

}
